# Conditional formating across different sheets w custom formula

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want to build a custom formula for formatting the background color of each cell of sheet `MyList`.

The tables in image above are in two separated sheets in the same spreadsheet. I want to format the sheet `MyList` in red if the value is not find in the sheet `MyKart`.

I tried the following formula, but it does not work:

```
IFERROR(if(MATCH(A1,MyKart!A:A,false)>0,true,false),false)=TRUE
```

The image below illustrates the result that I expect w the conditional formatting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In conditional formatting, when referring to a different sheet INDIRECT must be used**.

The formula should be

```
=IFERROR(if(MATCH(A1,INDIRECT("MyKart!A1:A"),false)>0,true,false),false)=TRUE
```

OR as mentioned by @basic

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("MyKart!A1:A"),A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use formula in CF:

```
=COUNTIF(MyKart!A:A,A1)
```

[image]

Comment: **In conditional formatting, when referring to a different sheet `INDIRECT` must be used**. The formula should be `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("MyKart!A1:A55"),A1)`